# Replace all occurrences of stirng in a string excluding other words starting with same characters

Tags: javascript, string

I want to replace all occurrences of string in a sentence but it should not replace other words starting with same string. Example If string is "abc bb bb bbcv cc ccv" and I want to replace bb and cc with "" so my expected output should be "abc bbcv cc".

I am using .replace method with but it is replacing bb and cc in word "bbcv" & "ccv" as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use `replace` and match a word boundary `\b` either side:

```js
const str = "abc bb bb bbcv cc ccv";
const res = str.replace(/\b(bb|cc)\b/g, "");
console.log(res);
```

You can get rid of the extra spaces as well:

```js
const str = "abc bb bb bbcv cc ccv";
const res = str.replace(/\b(bb|cc)\b/g, "").replace(/ {2,}/g, " ");
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the pattern `bb` or `cc` using alternation preceded and followed by word boundaries `\b` and one or more optional whitespaces.

[`Regex`](https://regex101.com/r/eBQhBW/3) - `/\b([\s+]?bb|cc[\s+]?)\b/ig`

```js
const str = "abc bb bb bbcv cc ccv";
const pattern = /\b([\s+]?bb|cc[\s+]?)\b/ig;
const replacedString = str.replace(pattern, function (match, p1) {
  return '';
});

console.log(replacedString);
```

Comment: this leaves probably unwanted whitespace where the characters were removed though.

Comment: @Bman70 updated my answer for handling those extra whitespaces

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shorter way, it removes every `space (\s)` followed by a word `bb` or `cc`:

```js
var str = 'abc bb bb bbcv cc ccv';
var res = str.replace(/\s(bb|cc)\b/g, '');
console.log(res);
```